# selection of uilabel with NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring, uitextviewdelegate

I want to nightlight text in label when user selects it by tapping on `UILabel` whole text like shown in picture. Those are appended `NSAttributedStrings`.

[image]

**example.**

```
Hy my name is Mohsin. my age is 22. I am doing development.
```

**Requirement :**

- when user taps on a word for example **Mohsin**, the sentence containing that word will be highlited.
- when I tap on Mohsin, hy my name is Mohsin, the whole sentence will be selected.
- I also want sentence position like `Hy my name is Mohsin` is a **1st sentence**,`my age is 22`. is **2nd sentence**

Comment: For that you need to use `UITextView` not `UILabel`

Comment: You can check this app on github it does what you want https://github.com/adilbenmoussa/Quran-Pro-iOS

Comment: he is using one ayah in one cell but i am using multiple ayaah in one cell textview or uilable and want to detect a selected ayah from that and highlight it